# very strange issue; different results from same table

Tags: sql, gridview, left-join

I am binding a gridview with some column from a database table, but it shows different results in Pane and in Gridview. see the attachted images.

[image]

[image]

see the marked records why they are different, although they are comming from the same table.

But yes for binding gridview I am using this query

```
SELECT mtblbuilding_budget_data.building_id, 
       mtblbuilding_budget_data.building_name, 
       mtblbuilding_budget_data.sanctioned_dpr, 
       mtblbuilding_budget_data.sanctioned_contract, 
       mtblblock.block_name 
FROM   mtblbuilding_budget_data 
       LEFT JOIN mtblblock 
              ON mtblblock.block_id = mtblbuilding_budget_data.block_id 
WHERE  mtblbuilding_budget_data.sfti_id = @SFTI_Id 
       AND mtblbuilding_budget_data.spmu_id = @SPMU_Id 
ORDER  BY mtblbuilding_budget_data.block_id
```

aspx code

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sanction (DPR)">

                          <ItemTemplate>
                                  <%#GetQTY1(float.Parse(Eval("Sanctioned_DPR").ToString())).ToString("N2")%>
                              </ItemTemplate>       
                             <FooterTemplate>
                                <%#GetTotalQTY1().ToString("N2")%>
                            </FooterTemplate>
                            <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" VerticalAlign="Top" />                            
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sanction (Contract)">

                       <ItemTemplate>
                                  <%#GetQTY2(float.Parse(Eval("Sanctioned_Contract").ToString())).ToString("N2")%>
                              </ItemTemplate>       
                             <FooterTemplate>
                                <%#GetTotalQTY2().ToString("N2")%>
                            </FooterTemplate>
                            <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" VerticalAlign="Top" />                            
                        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: is it the same query and the same database?

Comment: yes same query with same database

Comment: run the same query in the server by replacing  `@SFTI_Id`, `@SPMU_Id` which given in your program

Comment: after run, I asked the question here

Comment: This looks like a round problem `16` -> `20` and `88`->`90`. Mind you explain the logic behind your decimal dot and hundredish-commata?

Comment: see my gridview's template field code, I couldn't find anything wrong

Comment: try removing the .ToString("N2") from the GetQTY2(float.Parse(Eval("Sanctioned_Contract").ToString())).ToString("N2"), or replace the "N2" with "F0". http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Your grigview is rounding the values, check the next column on the same lines, it also as different results.
check the properties of your gridview e disable the round option.

Comment: then what is the solution Sir

Comment: check the gridview's and column's properties for rounding and/or format and correct that property, I don't have Visual Studio here, I would help you check, but I've seen that happen before.

Answer (score 0):

check the properties of your gridview e disable the round option. That's the solution..